# How can I allow duplicates in a custom Ordered Linked List class?

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I had an assignment where I was to create a custom Ordered Linked List from scratch. I was happy to receive an near perfect score on the assignment, but I was counted off for not allowing duplicates. Let's say I add "A", and then "A" again. It only prints one "A". Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could implement this? I'll show my add method. If anyone wants more code, feel free to ask and I'll gladly provide.

**NOTE**: The assignment is already complete, so it's already been graded.

```
  public boolean add(Comparable obj) {
    // TODO: Implement this method (8 points)

    //FOR REFERENCE - public OrderedListNode(Comparable item, OrderedListNode previous, OrderedListNode next) {

    try {
        OrderedListNode node; //create new OrderedListNode for comparison

        for (node = head; node.next != tail; node = node.next) { //loop one node at a time until next node is tail

            int compare = obj.compareTo(node.next.dataItem); //compare current object with next node

            if (compare == 0) {
                return false; // Nope
            }
            if (compare < 0) { //obj is less than next node, so insert previous next
                break;
            }
        }
        OrderedListNode newNode = new OrderedListNode(obj, node, node.next);
        newNode.next.previous = newNode; //swapping nodes
        node.next = newNode;
        System.out.println("Added: " + obj); //display elements added

        modCount++; //another modification
        theSize++; //increment size by 1

    } catch (ClassCastException e) { //give message to user
        System.out.println(RED + "Caught Exception" + RESET_COLOR);
        System.out.println("'" + obj +"'" + RED + " not added" + RESET_COLOR);
    }
    return true; //successful add
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (compare == 0) {
 return false; // Nope
}
if (compare < 0) { //obj is less than next node, so insert previous next
 break;
}
```

to

```
if (compare <= 0) { //obj is less than or equal next node, so insert previous next
 break;
}
```

To me it looks like this will allow you to still insert the item if it is equal to another item.

Comment: One moment. That makes sense. Gonna try it.

Comment: Nope. Not working yet. Note: I included the first if(compare == 0).

Comment: @IRGeekSauce don't include it - the first compare is returning out of the method if they are equal. That is one of the things we need to stop doing to solve your problem. If it still doesn't work after that let me know and I will look into it more.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce Thanks. By the way, props to you for caring enough to check on how to improve your code even after the assignment was graded.

Comment: You're very welcome. If I get points docked, I definitely want to know how I can make it work according to specifications. I guess I overlooked "allowing duplicates" in the instructions. Thanks for the props. :)